# failed to load cairo DLL on mac ARM

Tags: r, homebrew, cairo, homebrew-cask

I install R and Rstudio on my MacBook M1 ARM via brew but when I try to plot svg I get:

```
> svg("my_upset_plot.png", width = 1079, height = 463)
Warning messages:
1: In grSoftVersion() :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: <BBB44505-4BB3-30FA-9ED6-ABC69D534041> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/modules/R_X11.so
  Reason: tried: '/opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libSM.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libSM.6.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
2: In cairoVersion() :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library/grDevices/libs//cairo.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib
  Referenced from: <25AEF222-E381-3C27-AC91-0E12B2DF269A> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2-arm64/Resources/library/grDevices/libs/cairo.so
  Reason: tried: '/opt/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libXrender.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libXrender.1.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
3: In svg("my_upset_plot.png", width = 1079, height = 463) :
  failed to load cairo DLL
```

How can I fix it?

Thank you in advance